# Simple event broker / eventbus in C# (~100 lines of code)

Tags: c#, event-handling

**Background**
I was looking for a simple `Event Broker` or `EventBus` (whatever else keyword you can come up with) to use in a small(-ish) WinForms application. In Java I was using `org.greenrobot.EventBus` for a long time, but couldn't find a comparably established and *simple* solution in C# - everything looks to be enterprise grade. `Rebus` with in-memory transport seemed very promising, but it lacked unsubscription capabilities (I asked the author in [this question's followup comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59964763/rebus-how-to-register-an-instance-of-a-handler)).

So here's my first attempt to roll my own.

*If you know of a good solution that worked for you - please post it!*

**Question**: Does this implementation have some critical flaws?

**Some facts that I think are true about it:**

1. All listeners are notified on the same thread that published the event, so it's up to listeners to run tasks on correct threads.
2. You subscribe `Delegates`, so you can sub a static method, if need be.
3. Fast sub/unsub (should be O(1)), so it's ok to have tens of thousands of listeners for UI purposes.
4. As all sub/unsub/maintenance operations are synchronized (on the same object) it probably can't be too fast overall.

Point [1] is likely a problem. Not sure how to do it best.

**Code**

````
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

namespace DmtAvt.Bus {
    public class MiniBus : IDisposable {
        readonly object _lock = new object();
        readonly Dictionary<Type, LinkedList<MiniSub>> _subscriptions = new Dictionary<Type, LinkedList<MiniSub>>();
        readonly List<MiniSub> _recycling = new List<MiniSub>();
        public static readonly MiniBus Default = new MiniBus();

        public delegate void On<in T>(T asd);

        public MiniSub Sub<T>(On<T> d) {
            if (d.Method.IsAbstract || d.Method.IsGenericMethod)
                throw new ArgumentException("No generics or abstract methods");
            if (typeof(void) != d.Method.ReturnType)
                throw new ArgumentException("Registered delegates must have return type 'void'");
            ParameterInfo[] pis = d.Method.GetParameters();
            if (pis.Length != 1) throw new ArgumentException("Registered delegates must have exactly 1 parameter");
            Type messageType = pis[0].ParameterType;
            lock (_lock) {
                if (!_subscriptions.TryGetValue(messageType, out var forType)) {
                    forType = new LinkedList<MiniSub>();
                    _subscriptions.Add(messageType, forType);
                }

                var sub = new MiniSub(this, messageType, d);
                var node = new LinkedListNode<MiniSub>(sub);
                sub._listNode.SetTarget(node);
                forType.AddLast(node);
                return sub;
            }
        }

        public void UnSub(MiniSub sub) {
            lock (_lock) {
                if (_subscriptions.TryGetValue(sub._type, out var list)) {
                    if (sub._listNode.TryGetTarget(out var node)) {
                        try {
                            list.Remove(node);
                        }
                        catch (Exception) {
                            // It's ok if the node is already gone or some other unexpected
                            // circumstances happened, like the list itself is already gone, etc.
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void Pub(object message) {
            var type = message.GetType();
            _subscriptions.TryGetValue(type, out var subs);
            if (subs == null)
                return; // no one is subscribed to this topic
            foreach (var sub in subs) {
                if (!sub.TryHandleMessage(message)) {
                    _recycling.Add(sub);
                }
            }

            if (_recycling.Count > 0) {
                Maintenance();
            }
        }

        protected void Maintenance() {
            lock (_lock) {
                foreach (var l in _recycling) {
                    UnSub(l);
                }
                _recycling.Clear();
            }
        }

        public void Dispose() {
            lock (_lock) {
                foreach (var kv in _subscriptions) {
                    foreach (var sub in kv.Value) {
                        sub._bus.SetTarget(null);
                        sub._listNode.SetTarget(null);
                    }
                }

                _subscriptions.Clear();
                _recycling.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    public class MiniSub : IDisposable {
        internal readonly WeakReference<MiniBus> _bus;
        internal readonly Type _type;
        internal readonly WeakReference<LinkedListNode<MiniSub>> _listNode;
        public readonly WeakReference<Delegate> _delegate;

        internal MiniSub(MiniBus bus, Type type, Delegate del) {
            _bus = new WeakReference<MiniBus>(bus);
            _type = type;
            _listNode = new WeakReference<LinkedListNode<MiniSub>>(null);
            _delegate = new WeakReference<Delegate>(del);
        }

        internal bool TryHandleMessage(object o) {
            if (_delegate.TryGetTarget(out var d)) {
                d.DynamicInvoke(o);
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public void UnSub() {
            Dispose();
        }

        public void Dispose() {
            if (_bus.TryGetTarget(out var b)) {
                b.UnSub(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```
````